# how I can change default icon in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here I am working with chrome extension development.

my manifest.json page as show

```
{
"name": "DemoExtension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Official addon from demeo",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "star-on.png",
    "popup": "shopcmp.htm"  
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"    
  ],
  "background_page": "background.html"   
}
```

Here I want to change my default icon image at runtime.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to change the browser action default icon, just change

```js
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "star-on.png", //<--this line: change "star-on.png" to the icon you want
  "popup": "shopcmp.htm"  
},
```

That line indicates the default icon on first load of the extension.
To change the icon *in code*, call [`chrome.browserAction.setIcon(details)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html).

If you want to change the extension icon (the icons that shows during installation, in the Chrome Web Store, in the extension management page, and as a favicon), add an [`icons`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons) property to your manifest.json file.

Comment: For me browserAction is undefined in chrome. Can you please help?

Comment: But how to set *default*_icon in a runtime? I need to do this to avoid blinking while changing the icon.

Comment: @ciembor
Use chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon.png"});

Comment: What do different between browser_action and page_action in manifest file?

Comment: but the logo is not updating inside extension page... any clue for this? @DigitalPlane

Answer (score 21):

To change the default chrome extension pragmatically you can do:

```js
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "my-icon.png" });
```

or for custom sizes:

```js
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path: {
    19: "my-icon19.png"
  }
});
```

Full docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#method-setIcon

Comment: Also, if anyone here is wondering why Nathan specified a png image in his example, this is because **other image types would not work** in unpacked extension (actually in dev mode).
Source: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#type-ImageDataType

Comment: Is this path relative to background.js or a file that exist in the images folder?

Comment: If you are using manifest 3 you will need `chrome.action.setIcon`

Answer (score 7):

with the new manifest v3 the standard for changing an icon at runtime is now

```
chrome.action.setIcon()
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: if you are referencing an image within your extension folder, use **absolute** paths. For example, `/icon.png`, not `icon.png`, or you will trigger a Failed to fetch error.

Answer (score 0):

if you want every page has its own icon status, use `chrome.pageAction`.