# How to add an extension icon to the Chrome extension popup which lists extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The kinda "puzzle piece" icon of Chrome that shows a list of extension as a popup is shown in the image i have attached.  Next to each extension name is an icon. How do you add this icon to an extension or what image name or size is this in the manifest?

**Update** my default icon in the manifest looks like this.

```
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": {                    
  "16": "img/icon16.png",          
  "24": "img/icon24.png",           
  "32": "img/icon32.png"            
},
"default_title": "__MSG_mainDescription__"
}
```

**Update** This is now almost a stupid question. My icon color is almost the same color as the window and thus you cannot see it.  This was the problem.

[image: Image of the popup]

Comment: [how I can change default icon in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6939974)

Comment: are you suggesting it is the default_icon? I have added that part of my manifest as an update to the question.

Comment: It sure is. Just don't forget to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Thanks for making me look closer at it.  My icon color was the problem.  Almost a stupid question.